# Power BI Microsoft custom visual locked repo?

Tags: r, typescript, visual-studio, github, powerbi

[This is the link I will be referring to](https://github.com/microsoft/powerbi-visuals-spline)

I'm working with a Microsoft visual on Github. I have found a weird problem. No changes I make to the `capabilities.JSON` file will apply. I haven't even gotten the script to change. I went in and replaced all instances of the X axis variable with the Y, and vice-versa within the `script.r` file. Didn't work. 
I have deleted the package-lock file, that didn't work. I even opened *every single file* in this visual folder, searched for the old variables for capabilities, and found nothing. 
I went one step further and packaged the file to `visualname.pbiviz`, converted it to zip, opened the compressed file in a text editor, and *still* could not find anything that would revert it to the previous names.

The X axis is by default "X axis". I have changed it to be "Duration" in the `capabilities.json` file, but it will not stick.

If anyone has any insight as to what may be going on, or what Microsoft has done to prevent this visual from being modified, please inform me. I'm especially confused, because Microsoft has labeled this as an open source visual, yet changes are restricted. I'm new to creating/modifying visuals, so perhaps there is something I am just missing. Short of going in and deleting files at random, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: “Thanks for trying to help, but your edit isn’t what I meant. I’ve removed your edit, and have updated my question so it’s clearer." stackoverflow said it better than I could have.

Comment: The guidance (see e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/248731) is to remove salutations, and your experience with visuals is irrelevant to the question (maybe the next person with this problem *isn't* new to it, but they still might find the question and its answers useful). I didn't intend to be rude, sorry if it came across that way.

Comment: Referring to the salutations;"The first paragraph in your question is the second thing most readers will see, so make it as engaging and informative as possible." from Stackoverflow's own guidelines. It was an attempt at engagement, avoiding the generic 'here's my problem, help me fix it.' format. My intentions for including the part about me being a novice were to inform the reader that there could simply be something I missing due to this fact. If a reader thought I was an expert, or experienced, they could leave out a solution they would normally regard as common sense.

Comment: @BillO'Brien This is an R based visual using typescript and javascript for other files within this visual. Items in the script.r file could be causing my issues. I am not currently able to rule out R code as an issue considering how bizarre this issue is. Script.r is the primary work file for R visuals.  If I do discover that the R code is not the problem, I will edit the tags as needed. Still looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get this working. I found a bunch of http imports and things like that. What I am *assuming* was happening is it would ping whatever online repo it was told to, and re-import the files from there before compressing to `.pbiviz` instead of actually using the files in the visual folder... I copied the two main files I needed (`capabilities.json`, and `script.r`) and pasted them into a blank template visual. Everything is working fine and I can continue working on this like normal.

This is based on the assumption that files were being re-imported from an external source before being compressed. If anyone knows for certain what is going on here, feel free to leave an answer.